# Array reference is reused instead of cloned/copied - multiple instances of angular-bootstrap-nav-tree

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tree, angularjs-directive

I'm using Nick Perkin's tree directive (https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree) in my AngularJS application.

I want to show two trees based on the same data in two different UI Bootstrap tabs. The trees display different elements based on a filter.

My issue is that when I expand an element in one tree and then change to the tab containing the other tree, the other tree's element is also expanded and vice versa.

I guess the problem is somehow scope related, but the directive is written in a way that it creates an isolated scope. (At least I think so.)

It works fine when using two different data arrays, but strangely when I use a true copy of the data array (copied by using `arrayB = arrayA.slice();`), it doesn't work anymore and the expand/collapse state, etc. is again shared between both tree instances.

Is the mistake on my side or would I have to extend the directive by some sort of treeId? If so, how would I do that?

Example on Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/J0WIOkxEy7l0x9b5mqi4

Comment: Please make an example on something like http://jsbin.com. It's hard to debug something without seeing code. It's also against SO policies to post about code issues without including the code.

Comment: `Array.slice()` creates a shallow copy.

Comment: @m59 I added an example.

Comment: @zeroflagL My main issue is that I want both trees based on the same data, the copying thing was just something I played around with while trying to find the problem.

Comment: Isolated scope means that the directive can work with **different** data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `slice()` use this: `$scope.data2 = angular.copy($scope.data);`

The issue is that `slice()` is a shallow copy, so you're using the same object references in both instances of the directive. `angular.copy()` is deep, so that both are totally independent. **[Live demo here (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/CYe1RZWbsmZWJ1e375kS?p=preview)** See that the menus now operate separately.

Here's an example of passing in the same array, but having the directive itself make a copy and use that. You could further expand this to use a `$watch` to watch the original array, but always use a copy for the actual work. **[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/HFDHIK436lffu8N7uOG9?p=preview)**

Comment: As I wrote in my comment `Array.slice()` creates a shallow copy, while `angular.copy()` creates a deep one. `uid` is irrelevant. The OP's goal was to use the **same** array for both trees. And that's not possible. Other than that your solution is the way to go.

Comment: Okay, I guess I will have to make it work like this and find a way to keep my two copies of the tree data consistent. Thank you!

Comment: @muenchdo In that case, it's worth noting that you could pass the same array to the directive twice, then have the directive watch that array, but use a copy for the actual work.

Comment: @zeroflagL I updated my answer. Thanks =D I guess I was thinking too hard.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from m59 is correct -- you should use a deep copy of the "tree-data" if you need 2 trees.  The tree-data that you supply is not just the definition of the tree -- it will also be used to track it's state -- the tree adds an "expanded" attribute and  a "selected" attribute to each branch.  So, if you share tree data, then "expanded" states are also shared.  If you want 2 trees with separate state, then you need separate tree-data.

A better approach might be to keep the "tree-data" separate from your original data, whatever it is.  Use a function that loops over your original data, and creates the "tree-data" from it.

If you want to have 2 trees represent a common, shared set of data, then you could use the "branch.data" attributes of the branches to refer back to elements of your original data.  That is, have separate "tree data" for each tree, but have branches in both trees point to some shared data.

Suppose, for example that you have a list of "People", and you want to create 2 trees that both represent that same list of people.

First, write a function that loops over your list of people, and produces a new list of tree branches ( the "tree data" ).  For each branch, set the "branch.data" to point to the original "person" object from your list of people.

Now, run your function twice, to produce 2 separate sets of "tree data".  The result is 2 trees with separate state, but with "branch.data" on both trees referencing the same shared data.

Note that you must be careful about using a "deep copy" if you are also using "branch.data" -- you probably don't want to deep copy the branch data ( in the example, that would create a copy of each "Person" object referenced by branch.data, which is not what you want -- you want a shared reference )